# GCS JSON API multipart upload returns "code": 400, "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/png"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload images to Google Cloud Storage with multipart post, from a Google Apps Script. I set a bucket with public write permission. Everything works fine when uploading one file at a time, like this:

```
  function simpleUploadToGCS() {

    var blob1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.bkper.com/images/logo_beta_low.png").getBlob();

    var payload = new Object();

    payload.blob = blob1;

    var bucketNameOnGCS="your-bucket";
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/'+bucketNameOnGCS+'/o?name=image.png&key={yourKey}'

    var fetchArgs= new Object();
    var header={
      'x-goog-project-id': '{your-project-id}'
    }

    fetchArgs.headers = header;
    fetchArgs.payload = payload;
    fetchArgs.method = 'POST';

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs);
    Logger.log(result.getContentText());
    return result;
}
```

But I need to upload 8 files at a time, so, when trying to multipart upload, like this:

```
  function multipartUploadToGCS() {

    var blob1 =     UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.bkper.com/images/logo_beta_low.png").getBlob();
    var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.bkper.com/images/logo_beta_high.png").getBlob();

    var payload = new Object();
    payload.blob1 = blob1;
    payload.blob2 = blob2;


    var bucketNameOnGCS="bkper-gapps-addons";
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/'+bucketNameOnGCS+'/o?uploadType=multipart&key={your-project-key}'

    var fetchArgs= new Object();
    var header={
      'x-goog-project-id': 'your-project-id'
    }

    fetchArgs.headers = header;
    fetchArgs.payload = payload;
    fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
    fetchArgs.muteHttpExceptions = true;

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs);
    Logger.log(result.getContentText());
    return result;
  }
```

**I get the error:**

```
   "error": {
    "errors": [
     {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "badContent",
      "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/png"
     }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/png"
   }
  }
```

This is a simple code for sample purposes only and the multipart post data is created by FetchUrl service, but it looks right. I already implemented the multipart content exactly as it is in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#multipart), but I get the same error above.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Multipart upload is not for uploading multiple objects in one transaction. Rather, it's a way to upload an object and specify metadata properties for it simultaneously.

Multipart uploads must contain exactly two parts. First, an application/json part specifying the metadata, and second, the data for the object being uploaded, as whatever type it is.

If you want to upload 8 objects at a time, I suggest using 8 separate connections.

Comment: Maybe I can use batch requests, that actually uses multipart :) [https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch)